# "Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.todoList' on port 8609" on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android, and i'm following a book to learn it. there is a simple todo list example that i copied to the computer and am trying to run.

But every time i run it, i get this log:

```
[2011-11-19 14:44:00 - Todo_List] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.todoList' on port 8609
```

and a few lines above it says `adb is running normally`.

On the emulator i see for a second this message `application Todo_List(process com.todoList) is waiting for the debugger to attach.` and then it runs - with the debugger

And i have to restart the virtual device every time, because the second time i try to run the application without restart i get this in the DDMS console:

```
[2011-11-19 14:48:58 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:672)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
`
```

In general - I have no idea whats wrong. just guessing the emulator isn't set up correctly.

have tryed:

- making a new AVD
- searching this site, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950523/android-null-pointer-exception) i found someone has the same thing - but no answer
- adding `android:debuggable="true"` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>` to the manifest

having this for 2 days now.. :-\